# How do I convert a remote JSON object to an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, icecast

I am trying to take the JSON object from my Icecast server and turn it into an array so that I can access the current listener numbers stat and display it in html.

Here's my JS:

```
const endpoint = 'http://stream.8k.nz:8000/status-json.xsl';    
const serverStats = [];

fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => serverStats.push(data));
```

This just adds the object as a single item in the array. The ES6 method spread doesn't work as it only works on arrays.

Comment: If you've called `.json()` on it, then it's not a JSON anymore, it's an object. JSON is a *way of formatting a string*. What is `data`, could you give an example of the current output is and what you want the output to be?

Comment: There is just one object returned. What are you expecting?

Comment: I was stuck thinking that I needed to turn an object into an array to access the contents of it. All I want out of the object is the value of the property "listeners".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for array. You are only receiving a single object and the properties you want are easily accessible from that object

```js
const endpoint = 'http://stream.8k.nz:8000/status-json.xsl';    
const serverStats = [];

fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data =>{
        let source = data.icestats.source;
       // console.log(source)
        console.log('Listeners =', source.listeners, ' Peak=', source.listener_peak)


       console.log('\n ******************* \n')
       // to iterate over all the source key/values
       Object.keys(source).forEach(k=> console.log(k,'=', source[k]))
    
    })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important;}
```